# error while installing web3 in ubuntu

Tags: web3js

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/we                                                                             b3/node_modules/sha3/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-70-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gy                                                                             p/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/web3/node_modules/sha3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sha3@1.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sha3@1.2.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log                                                                             ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yuching/.npm/_logs/2019-11-27T17_08_23_043Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Well... have you checked to see what's inside file `/home/yuching/.npm/_logs/2019-11-27T17_08_23_043Z-debug.log`? It might actually tell you a lot.

Comment: Hi! I see a "permission denied", have you tried with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try

- `sudo chmod 777 ~/.node_modules`
- If this doesnt work, try it with installing it with the unsafe perm option

`sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm`

- If this doesnt work try to rebuild `node gyp`

`sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm`